# Could not load GORM service when configuring spring-security-core

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I have a grails 3.3.6 application configured with a REST profile using gorm version 6.1.10. When I added these dependencies, I began having issues with configuration. In my build.gradle file:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M1"
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.1.2"
```

I have a users table titled 'App_User' and a role table titled 'Role'. I do not use the default user table name since it is a reserved word in Postgres. The spring-security tables were generated using the `s2-quickstart` script found [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/#configGroovy). Additionally, the rest plugin is found [here](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/#_articles_and_sample_projects).

It is confirmed that hibernate generates the correct tables and fields in my db. However, my app fails and gives the following relevant error:

```
2018-11-27 14:44:07.007 ERROR --- [           main] o.g.d.m.services.DefaultServiceRegistry  : Could not load GORM service: org.grails.datastore.mapping.services.Service: Provider charity.navigator.rest.$App_UserServiceImplementation not found

java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.grails.datastore.mapping.services.Service: Provider charity.navigator.rest.$App_UserServiceImplementation not found
```

I can provide an additional stack trace if needed.

I do not have an explicit service for the 'App_User' domain since I want to rely on spring-security to do all the work. If I need one, please provide a link to a working project that I can model.

For some context, I am loosely following [this](http://sergiodelamo.es/how-to-use-spring-security-core-to-secure-you-grails-3-app/) tutorial but with some necessary extensions.

Since I am also not sure what is precisely causing the error and because I do not want to publish the entire project, I am willing to provide some additional source code and context if needed.

Comment: Have you tried to name this domain class as AppUser already?

Comment: That didn't help. I get the exact error. It seems the app is looking for the incorrect service. I cannot locate where it is to change the configuration.

Comment: Do you have a minimal demo app containing dependencies + this domain class? If so, share the code